# Elixir Phoenix setting and using environment variables

Tags: oauth, elixir, phoenix-framework, ueberauth

I have a phoenix app that is making an OAuth call to github. I want to store my secret keys as environment variables so I can keep them out of version control.

I have created a file called `.env` where I define my private key:

```
export GITHUB_CLIENT_ID="891538_my_key_bf0055"
```

I attempt to obtain my private key in my `config.exs` file, the file responsible for configuring your application using `System.Config`.

`config :ueberauth, Ueberauth.Strategy.Github.OAuth,
    client_id: System.get_env("GITHUB_CLIENT_ID"),
    client_secret: System.get_env("GITHUB_SECRET_ID")`

To make a long story short, my controller is almost able to handshake with github for the request. When I make a request to github to authorize my app, `http://localhost:4000/auth/github`, I can almost make a request and I see a 404 page from github. I have noticed that the url has no `client_id` though!

My router to access the callback is

```
  scope "/auth", Discuss do
    pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

    # make request to github, google, fb
    get "/:provider", AuthController, :request
    get "/:provider/callback", AuthController, :callback
  end
```

And what I get is URL with no `value`
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?**client_id=**&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4000%2Fauth%2Fgithub%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=user%2Cpublic_repo`

**If I don't use an environment variable in `config.exs` and instead use the string value**, the request work as it should.

How do I use environment variables in Phoenix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using Distillery releases, you may want to avoid using `System.get_env/1` from inside the `config.exs` files, as it will store the value of the environment variable at build time, rather than runtime.

In the `prod.exs` configuration, you can use

```
config :ueberauth, Ueberauth.Strategy.Github.OAuth,
    client_id: "${GITHUB_CLIENT_ID}",
    client_secret: "${GITHUB_SECRET_ID}"
```

Then generate the release with `REPLACE_OS_VARS=true` environment variable set.

[Distillery Docs](https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/master/docs/Runtime%20Configuration.md#runtime-configuration)

Comment: Tonight I'll check out the Distillery docs and see how I can implement this to my project. If all goes well, I'll mark this as the correct answer. Thank you Mike!

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't wrap the `client_id` string with double quotes. Write it as is :

`export GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=891538_my_key_bf0055`

Before launching your server or IEx, don't forget to `source .env`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your ENV vars to stay visible only in the process of your app you can put them in the **.env** file and execute your app with

`env $(cat .env | grep -v ^# | xargs) iex -S mix phoenix.server`

Of course, in production you might want to try some more sophisticated mechanism but the above works ok for simple/dev use case and it will let you know if your application is reading the ENV var correctly.

Comment: This is what my research has been leading me too. I've found that in production, it would be best to store these variables in `prod.secret.exs`. If I were to store my keys in this file, then how can I access them? Currently, for development, this is how I am obtaining my keys. https://github.com/Fallenstedt/elixir-discuss/blob/master/config/config.exs#L35-L37

Answer (score 0):

For development – when running by `iex -S mix phx.server` – you can set the variables in `.iex.exs`:

```
System.put_env(%{"GITHUB_CLIENT_ID" => "891538_my_key_bf0055",
                 "GITHUB_SECRET_ID" => "1234567890asdfghjkls"})
```